# Going Back To Main App After Launching Intent Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, pdf, android-intent, xamarin

I have an android app I am developing on Visual Studio Xamarin.Android
In my app I create a .pdf file and launch any .pdf apps using an intent.
Code Below...

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.TaskOnHome | ActivityFlags.NewTask );
            StartActivity(intent);
```

My question is: When I click the back button on the application I opened using the intent, it goes to the android home screen. How do I make it go back to the application it was launched from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StartActivityForResult` and `OnActivityResult`
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: I have tried to use this however the .pdf application does not return a result. It's purely used for viewing or printing. Once the user has finished printing or viewing the .pdf he/she will need to continue back into the application that the intent was launched from.